# Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device on Fedora 18: No drivers?

Tags: fedora, drivers, intel

I've just installed Fedora 18 on an old laptop, and it seems I can't get drivers for the graphics card.

"Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device" is what `lspci` is reporting, but I'm struggling to find proprietary drivers, or a package for it.

I've added RPM Fusion packages, but still, no drivers.

Where (if there are any at all) do I get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There are no proprietary drivers for that video card.](http://www.x.org/wiki/IntelGraphicsDriver) The driver is contained in the `xorg-x11-drv-intel` package.

Comment: ...which is already installed. Any ideas how to improve video with this graphics card? Thanks for your clarifying!

Comment: In what way would you like to improve it?

Comment: For instance, having OpenGL working...

Comment: Did you had to do something? Like, editing xorg.conf?